# I am fetching two table data with the help of PHP and MySQL but not fetching proper data

Tags: php, mysql, join

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM enquiry_form LEFT 
JOIN mstpackage ON enquiry_form.no_of_days=mstpackage.no_of_days 
ORDER BY enquiry_form.id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<?php 
for($i=1;$i<=$result;$i++)
{
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

After fetching data show something like that

[image]

If I am clicking any generated link through the id for single record then only data show last inserted record something like that

[image]

You can see first image id is 20 and name is AK but data showing 21 id you can see above the

Actually, data fetch last record correctly in this type but I am clicking old enquiry data then URL is proper and id is proper but inside the content data change last inserted record

Answer (score 1):

This

```
ORDER BY enquiry_form.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

means your query will always return the record with the greatest id.  If you want a different record you will need to pass that in to your query somehow.  I suggest using PDO and a bound parameter.

Comment: Thanks for answering  if i am using pdo method then data is not showing. only available page content is not available on page

Comment: If you want the row with a different id, you'll need to pass that in to the query somehow.  PDO is a fairly standard and safe way to do this.  If you want to add your PDO code here we can take a look and see if we can help make it work.

Comment: can you give me some line of code for this? bcz i don't understand how to do..

Comment: I suggest you read https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php - there are a few example queries shown on this page that you should be able to adapt to your needs